# Neo4j/Cypher: Filter edges between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to filter the edges between the two nodes according to the an edge property. However, only the nodes are getting filtered when I use the following Cypher query.

```
MATCH (s:Source {id: 54558})-[r:CCI{prop_1: 8}]->(t:Target)
with s, collect(r) as filterededges, t return s, filterededges, t
```

[image]

In the "Table" output, it is showing the correct result (one edge from the source node to the target node) How can I remove the unwanted edges that are displayed?
I am using Neo4j version 5.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's in your browser settings; uncheck the CONNECT nodes option. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct and this is an artefact of the visualisation. Go to the settings and un-check the option to connect result nodes (see https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-settings/#adjust-in-browser)